# Twitterizer - The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

Most answers to this questions suggest to make sure your Twitter app is setup as a "web app" and not a "desktop app"... in the current Twitter dev site... I do not see this option.

I also made sure to provide a callback URL when first setting up my app.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Providing a callback URL is what makes it a "web app". There should be an error message returned with the 401 that should say what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API returns a 401 when the OAuth tokens you've provided are revoked/invalid or any time you attempt an action for which you do not have access. For example, if your application is read-only and it attempts to post a tweet, a 401 will be returned.

Twitter does provide an error message and Twitterizer will return that to you when it can. It is in the `ErrorMessage` property of the response.

Answer (score 3):

Use the callback url for your app. For local development, you can use 127.0.0.1 or proxied address like http://www.localhost.com. Then, error will disappear. Thanks.